# how to install pyHook on windows 10

Tags: python-3.x, pyhook

I Did donwnload the package from: 
[lfd.uci.edu](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyhook)

But when I run it from command prompt:

```
pip install pyHook-1.5.1-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl
```

I get this error:

```
pyHook-1.5.1-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

I have tried the 32 bit and 64bit version, but have the same error.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

**.whl** files can be installed using:

```
wheel install your_file_name.whl
```

Wheel documentation here: https://wheel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

use your python version as below :-

```
pip3.5 install pyHook-1.5.1-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl
```